# What is the Victorian government's long-term COVID-19 strategy for reopening borders?

Tags: covid-19, australia, public-health

The Victorian (Australia) government is enforcing [strict quarantining rules](https://www.dhhs.vic.gov.au/stage-4-restrictions-covid-19#:%7E:text=From%206pm%20on%20Sunday%202,work%2C%20medical%20care%20and%20caregiving.) to reduce the number of COVID-19 cases. The short-term strategy detailed in the daily press release, [published on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I_JYl6PuZjE), is to attempt to reduce daily cases to zero, as quickly as possible.

**Stage 4 restrictions** are currently enforced, limiting *most* normal social interaction.

From the Victorian Government website:

> From 6pm on Sunday 2 August, if you live in metropolitan Melbourne, Stage 4 restrictions apply.
>
> A curfew is in place between the hours of 8pm until 5am. This means you must be at your home during these hours. The only reasons to leave home between 8pm and 5am will be work, medical care and caregiving.
>
> The four reasons that you can leave home remain, but further limitations are now in place for:
> shopping for food or other essential items
> exercise (applies to outdoor exercise, and with only one other person)
> permitted work
>
> Caregiving, for compassionate reasons or to seek medical treatment also remains a permitted reason to leave home.

However, I cannot find any official release that details a long-term strategy to reopen internationally, once the daily cases reach a *tolerable level* and the stage 4 restrictions are lifted.

This bothers me, because my feeling is that to maintain a daily COVID-19 case rate of zero (or close to it), international borders cannot be reopened... possibly ever? Other countries, such as the USA have far less strict [social distancing protocols](https://floridahealthcovid19.gov/frequently-asked-questions/) which are not compatible with Victoria's social distancing rules.

**This leads me to my question:**

What is the Victorian government's long-term COVID-19 strategy for eventually reopening borders?

Comment: Well, international borders can be reopened with New Zealand, and  South Korea, and Taiwan, and Vietnam, and any other countries that can be persuaded to successfully fight coronavirus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find it likely that no such plan is yet in place. [In a *Financial Review* story](https://www.afr.com/politics/federal/business-wants-nsw-victoria-border-reopened-20200708-p55a4m) the border restrictions are described as "quickly designed". [According to Reuters](https://www.reuters.com/article/us-health-coronavirus-australia/australia-closes-state-border-for-first-time-in-100-years-after-covid-19-spike-idUSKBN247074), "**NSW Premier Gladys Berejiklian said there was no timetable for reopening the border**".

Comment: That border she was referring to in that Reuters was the NSW/VIC border, not the international border.

Answer (score 4):

This question is based on a misconception. The Victorian Government does **not** and did not have a strategy to reopen international borders, because they are not responsible for international borders, only for state borders.

The Federal Government is responsible for international borders, and currently is a bit cagey about how and when they are going to reopen those borders.